# Added a image upload progress bar (Paperclip, Javascript), but images themselves are not being saved. How can I fix this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, cloudinary

**UPDATE FIVE**

I've just did a debugger and this is the log (arrow appears at line 61), so it looks like the product item would just fail.

```
   47:  def create
   48:    @product = Product.new(product_params)
   49:
   50:    respond_to do |format|
   51:      if @product.save
   52:
   53:        if params[:images]
   54:          params[:images].each { |image|
   55:            @product.pictures.create(image: image)
   56:          }
   57:        end
   58:        flash[:notice] = "The product was successfully added."
   59:        redirect_to show_product_path and return
   60:      else
=> 61:        flash[:notice] = "The product was not able to be saved."
   62:        redirect_to new_product_path and return
   63:      end
   64:    end
   65:  end
```

**UPDATE FOUR**

My apologies, as the previous update, I left something out in the Product controller, just the redirect command.

```
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save

        if params[:images]
          params[:images].each { |image|
            @product.pictures.create(image: image)
          }
        end
        flash[:notice] = "The product was successfully added."
        redirect_to show_product_path and return
      else
        flash[:notice] = "The product was not able to be saved."
        redirect_to new_product_path and return
      end
    end
  end
```

**UPDATE THREE**

I just realised since I had removed some code, I may have left out something essential. I do have a User model, which is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Essentially, the user creates a product, the product itself has images tied to it through the pictures model. I hope that explains things a bit more clearly.

**UPDATE TWO**

I am still receiving the same error as above, but I've updated the models as follows:

(Changed users to user, forget to add in the foreign_key, optional: true does not work, error is this is an unknown key)

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'user_id', optional: true
  has_many :pictures, :dependent => :destroy
end


class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product, optional: true
  has_attached_file :image,
    :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:id/:filename",
    :url  => "/images/:id/:filename"

  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image
end
```

**UPDATE ONE**

This is the log for when I am uploading the images:

```
Started POST "/products" for [IP ADDRESS] at [DATE AND TIME]
Processing by ProductsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f621971b808 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20190227-181-kldesh.JPG>,     @original_filename="book1.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg",     @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";     filename=\"book1.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "product"=>    {"name"=>"test"}}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 21]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/products/new
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

Essentially, the images can't be saved and it's redirecting back to the products new page. I can't figure out why this is the case.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

So I've got a basic image upload system using Paperclip (which allows for multiple image uploads and they are associated with each product created). My issue is now trying to add in an image upload progress bar, and after searching around, it sounds like Jquery is the best for this.

I've been following this: https://github.com/hayageek/jquery-upload-file and I just can't get it to work.

So I have "Products", which itself is linked to "Pictures". Products has a one to many relationship with Pictures.

Schema:

```
  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.integer  "image"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "pictures", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "image"
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "product_token"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end
```

Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  has_many :pictures, :dependent => :destroy
end


class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  has_attached_file :image,
    :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:id/:filename",
    :url  => "/images/:id/:filename"

  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image
end
```

Controller (Products):

(I've intentionally left out some stuff, but I figured the main thing would be the create action)

```
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save

        if params[:images]
          params[:images].each { |image|
            @product.pictures.create(image: image)
          }
        end
        flash[:notice] = "The product was successfully added."
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @product, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        flash[:notice] = "The product was not able to be saved."
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

View (for products new) (Again, I've removed code just to show the most relevant stuff):

```
<%= form_for @product, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal', multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :description, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :description, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :pictures, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Show (for products):

```
        <td> Name </td>
        <td> <%= @product.name %> </td>
    <div class = "images_styling"> Photos </div>
    <% @products.pictures.each do |picture| %>
    <%= image_tag picture.images.url(:medium) %>
    <% end %>
```

Now this is what I've attempted to do:

(Added a fileUpload id, and a save id in submit)

View for new products form

```
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :pictures, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls" id="fileUpload" >
      <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="save" class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
```

And this is the script I obtained online (this is present in the view for new products form):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {

      var fileUpload = $("#fileUpload").uploadFile({
      url: "/products",
      multiple: true,
      autoSubmit: false,
      showCancel: false,
      showAbort: false,
      dragDrop: true,
      maxFileCount: 4,
      showPreview: true,
      showProgress: true,
      showStatusAfterSuccess: true,
      dynamicFormData: function () {
        var name = $('#product_name').val();
        var data = {"product[name]": name};
        return data;
      }
    });

    $("#save").click(function (e) {
      $("#save").prop("disabled", true);
      fileUpload.startUpload();
      e.preventDefault();
    });


  });

</script>
```

But it doesnt work. Rather, it does a "begins" then "rollbacks" when I click the submit button. Interestingly, the button does show an upload progress bar for each image.

However, the images, when I look at the "show" for the product, is not there. I guess the images are not saving to the product, due to the "rollback". I've looked at the log and it seems there isn't anything substantial in it.

Based on this, what could I do to get this to work? Is there an easier way to implement what I want to do?

Comment: You got the console log output?

Comment: Hi cd-rum, I just added it now.

Comment: What version of Rails are you running? Try adding `optional: true` to your relations.

Comment: Also, `belongs_to :users` (i.e., plural and not `user`) seems like a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Rails 5+ makes all `belongs_to` relations [required by default](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html). Solve your problem either by setting `:user` and `:product` in your form or controller or model, or make both `optional: true`.

Also you can't have a `belongs_to :users` (i.e., belongs-to-many isn't a thing).

Comment: Hi cd-rum. Thanks for the reply. It's bizarre, I've done the following:

Product model

```belongs_to :user``` 

Regarding the optional: true, I realised I forgot to add in the foreign_key for the Product model (as I was making sure to remove certain code, and missed this)

So it would be:

```belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'user_id'```

If I add in the ```optional: true```, it doesn't work, as it states its an "unknown key"

I could add  the ```optional: true``` to products, though.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the log, execution never succeeds at the `if @product.save` line of `ProductsController#create`.

Using the logger or a debugger, can you tell if execution enters the action at all?

Is there any `before_action` or `around_action` in that controller or any superclass (including mixins) that redirects to `/products/new`?

---

Ah, so the `@product.save` is failing. Change it to `@product.save!`, which will raise an exception instead of returning "success false" and take a look at what the exception raised is.

Comment: Hi Kache, thank you for the reply.

I realised  that I left out some code for the Products controller (as I tried to keep it as concise as possible), but the redirect to products/new is if the Products create method fails.

Regarding your question, I've looked and there isn't any before_action or around_action in the controller.

If you require more information, please tell me.

Comment: I apologise, I skipped over your 1st question. I'm actually a junior RoRs dev, so I haven't used logger/debugger before. I'll try and see what I can do

Comment: Hi Kache, so I just did debugger now, and I've updated the question (since it's a little too long to psot as a comment)

Comment: Hi @JamesWu, I made an update a while ago, can you check again? If it was helpful, it'd be great to get my answer accepted.

Comment: Hi Kache, apologies as I've just done it now. Annoyingly, I've going to put this on the back burner now as it's been quite a frustrating experience getting this to work. I've awarded you the points, however.